# Multiple If conditions in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, if-statement, jsx

I'm facing with an "If" issue inside JSX Return() in my code when one of my conditions have 2 different 'onClick' events.
I have 2 'a' tags, which one of them will display button 'X' if the statement is true, and the other will display button 'Y' if not.
Both of them have an 'onClick' event.

For example:

```
{isNew ? <a id="add_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": 
!isRowValid })} onClick={this.onAddRow}><i className="fa fa-lg fa-plus-circle"/></a> : <a id="delete_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": enabled || !isRowValid })} onClick={onRemoveDomain}><i className="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle"/></a>}
```

I also have this 'a' tag which I want to add in case that '!enabled',

```
<a id="remove_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": !enabled || !isRowValid })} onClick={this.openModal}><i className="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle"/></a>}
```

I've tried the following:

```
if (isNew) {
            domain_status = <a id="add_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": !isRowValid })} onClick={this.onAddRow}><i className="fa fa-lg fa-plus-circle"/></a>;
        } else {
            domain_status = enabled && !isRowValid ?
               <a id="delete_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": !enabled || !isRowValid })} onClick={this.openModal}><i className="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle"/></a> :
               <a id="delete_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": enabled || !isRowValid })} onClick={this.onRemoveDomain}><i className="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle"/></a>;
        }
```

and also tried to do this:

```
<div>
(()=> {
if (isNew) {
   return add_icon;
 } else if (!isNew && enabled) {
   return remove_icon;
 } else (!isNew && !enabled)
   return remove_icon_modal;
 })
}
</div>
```

I'm expecting to be able and use the if condition to be able and to create 2 option of 'onClick' event if one of the conditions is false.

**Found solution:**

```
    renderAddButton (isRow){
        return (
            <a id="add_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": !isRow })} onClick={this.onAddRow}><i className="fa fa-lg fa-plus-circle"/></a>
        )
    }

    renderRemovebutton (isRow){
        const {onRemoveDomain} = this.props;
        const {enabled} = this.state;
        if(!enabled) {
            return (
                <a id="delete_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": enabled })} onClick={onRemoveDomain}><i className="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle"/></a>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <a id="delete_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": !enabled || !isRow })} onClick={this.openModal}><i className="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle"/></a>
            )
        }
    }
```

```
<td className="table-action">
  { isNew ? this.renderAddButton(isRowValid):
   this.renderRemovebutton(enabled, isRowValid, onRemoveDomain)
  }
</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried a google search or read the official documentation?

Comment: Yes but didn't find something that looks like what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice approach for conditional rendering of multiple parts is creating functions for each part/condition and use them in the main render method.

For example:

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
    renderButton() {
        if (true) { // condition here
            return <button>btn</btn>
        }
    }

    renderText() {
        if (true) { //condition here
            return 'Text'
        }
    }

    render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <p>this is common part </>
               { this.renderButton() }
               { this.renderText() }
           </div>
       )
    }
}
```

Of course you should paste real conditions instead of `true` inside `if` blocks. If condition resolves as falsy, then nothing is returned, so nothing will be rendered in that particular place where you called the function.

Comment: Found a solution based on your example! - Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a ternary inside your onClick.

```
<a id="delete_domain" className={cx({ "disabled": !enabled || !isRowValid })} 
   onClick={enabled && !isRowValid ? this.openModal : this.onRemoveDomain}>
     <i className="fa fa-lg fa-times-circle"/>
</a>
```